# Update listbox output with a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox, tryparse

I'm trying to update a listbox output of a .csv file using a textbox + button. I'm supposed to use TryParse for updating the "quantity" of a selected item in the listbox. I'm not really sure how to implement the TryParse and update the "quantity" value in the listbox.

This is currently what I have coded for the button:

```
decimal value1;
    private void updateSoldQtyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.outputListBox.SelectedIndex == -1) //checks if an item in the listbox has been selected
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please selected an inventory item to increment sold qty");
        } else if (qtySoldTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input a numerical value in the corresponding text box");
        } else if (!decimal.TryParse(qtySoldTextBox.Text, out value1))
        {

        }
    }
```

Here's how the .csv is being loaded into the listbox:

```
private void InvLoad(Inventory InventoryItems) //method
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try //try catch
            {
                List<Inventory> InventoryList = new List<Inventory>();
                StreamReader ipFile = File.OpenText("inventory_ip.csv"); //input file is the csv
                outputListBox.Items.Clear(); //clear listbox
                ipFile.ReadLine(); //skips the first line
                while (!ipFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] items; //tokenize
                    string itemz = ipFile.ReadLine();
                    items = itemz.Split(','); //, splits the text into columns
                    Inventory InvList = new Inventory();
                    //fields
                    InvList.ID = items[0];
                    InvList.ItemName = items[1];
                    InvList.StartingQty = int.Parse(items[2]);
                    InvList.MinRestockQty = int.Parse(items[3]);
                    InvList.SoldQty = int.Parse(items[4]);
                    InvList.RestockedQty = int.Parse(items[5]);
                    InvList.UnitPrice = decimal.Parse(items[6]);
                    //formatted string
                    string invOp = InvList.ID.PadRight(12, ' ') + 
                            InvList.ItemName.PadRight(23, ' ') + 
                            InvList.StartingQty.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ') + 
                            InvList.MinRestockQty.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ') + 
                            InvList.SoldQty.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ') + 
                            InvList.RestockedQty.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ') + 
                            InvList.UnitPrice.ToString("c").PadRight(10, ' ');
                    InventoryList.Add(InvList);
                    outputListBox.Items.Add(invOp); //output string invOP to listbox
                }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //exception msg
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
else if (!qtySoldTextBox.Text == decimal.TryParse(qtySoldTextBox.Text))
```

on your first else if, and then

```
else if (qtySoldTextBox.Text == decimal.TryParse(qtySoldTextBox.Text))
```

on the second one.
The first hits true if it doesn't parse. You can update the quantity if you get true the second time.
Then just update your messages to reflect what happened.